# Delete an Entity row using Composite Key Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, key, composite

Embedable Class

```
@Embeddable
public class SaTaskInterfacesId implements java.io.Serializable {

    // Fields

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4070669691040083979L;
    private Long processRuleId;
    private Long interfaceCode;

    // Constructors

    /** default constructor */
    public SaTaskInterfacesId() {
    }

    /** full constructor */
    public SaTaskInterfacesId(Long processRuleId, Long interfaceCode) {
        this.processRuleId = processRuleId;
        this.interfaceCode = interfaceCode;
    }

    // Property accessors

    @Column(name = "PROCESS_RULE_ID")
    public Long getProcessRuleId() {
        return this.processRuleId;
    }

    public void setProcessRuleId(Long processRuleId) {
        this.processRuleId = processRuleId;
    }

    @Column(name = "INTERFACE_CODE")
    public Long getInterfaceCode() {
        return this.interfaceCode;
    }

    public void setInterfaceCode(Long interfaceCode) {
        this.interfaceCode = interfaceCode;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if ((this == other))
            return true;
        if ((other == null))
            return false;
        if (!(other instanceof SaTaskInterfacesId))
            return false;
        SaTaskInterfacesId castOther = (SaTaskInterfacesId) other;

        return ((this.getProcessRuleId() == castOther.getProcessRuleId()) || (this
                .getProcessRuleId() != null
                && castOther.getProcessRuleId() != null && this
                .getProcessRuleId().equals(castOther.getProcessRuleId())))
                && ((this.getInterfaceCode() == castOther.getInterfaceCode()) || (this
                        .getInterfaceCode() != null
                        && castOther.getInterfaceCode() != null && this
                        .getInterfaceCode()
                        .equals(castOther.getInterfaceCode())));
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        int result = 17;

        result = 37
                * result
                + (getProcessRuleId() == null ? 0 : this.getProcessRuleId()
                        .hashCode());
        result = 37
                * result
                + (getInterfaceCode() == null ? 0 : this.getInterfaceCode()
                        .hashCode());
        return result;
    }

}


Entity Class

@Entity
@Table(name = "SA_TASK_INTERFACES")
public class WorkFlowTaskInterface2Entity extends BaseEntity  {
    private SaTaskInterfacesId id;
//  private Long saWorkflowRules;
    private Short sortOrder;
    private String itemCsv;
    private String personCodeCsv;


    // Property accessors
    @EmbeddedId
    @AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name = "processRuleId", column = @Column(name = "PROCESS_RULE_ID" )),
    @AttributeOverride(name = "interfaceCode", column = @Column(name = "INTERFACE_CODE" )) })
    public SaTaskInterfacesId getId() {
    return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(SaTaskInterfacesId id) {
    this.id = id;
    }


    @Column(name = "SORT_ORDER" )
    public Short getSortOrder() {
    return this.sortOrder;
    }

    public void setSortOrder(Short sortOrder) {
    this.sortOrder = sortOrder;
    }

    @Column(name = "ITEM_CSV", length = 50)
    public String getItemCsv() {
    return this.itemCsv;
    }

    public void setItemCsv(String itemCsv) {
    this.itemCsv = itemCsv;
    }

    @Column(name = "PERSON_CODE_CSV", length = 150)
    public String getPersonCodeCsv() {
    return this.personCodeCsv;
    }

    public void setPersonCodeCsv(String personCodeCsv) {
    this.personCodeCsv = personCodeCsv;
    }
}


Deletion Query Sample

    public void taskInterfaceDeletion(WorkFlowTaskInterface2Entity workFlowTaskInterface2Entity) {

        baseORMDao.executeQuery("DELETE FROM WorkFlowTaskInterface2Entity entity WHERE entity.interfaceCode="+(long)58+" AND entity.processRuleId="+(long)112301+"");

    }
```

Error is:

could not resolve property: interfaceCode of: pk.gov.fbr.insys.entity.workflow.WorkFlowTaskInterface2Entity [DELETE FROM pk.gov.fbr.insys.entity.workflow.WorkFlowTaskInterface2Entity entity WHERE entity.interfaceCode=58 AND entity.processRuleId=112301]; nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: interfaceCode of: pk.gov.fbr.insys.entity.workflow.WorkFlowTaskInterface2Entity [DELETE FROM pk.gov.fbr.insys.entity.workflow.WorkFlowTaskInterface2Entity entity WHERE entity.interfaceCode=58 AND entity.processRuleId=112301]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is very obnious from the stacktrace. `interfaceCode` property is declared in `SaTaskInterfacesId` and this class is not parent class to `WorkFlowTaskInterface2Entity` and thus the property is not found.